# Insertion sort not functioning - 32bit assembly

Tags: assembly, 32-bit, insertion-sort

I'm trying to implement insertion sort in 32bit assembly in linux using NASM but something goes wrong.
Here is the code:

```
section .rodata
MSG:    DB  "welcome to sortMe, please sort me",10,0
S1: DB  "%d",10,0 ; 10 = '\n' , 0 = '\0' 

section .data

array   DD 5,1,7,3,4,9,12,8,10,2,6,11   ; unsorted array
len DB 12   

section .text
    align 16
    global main
    extern printf

main:
    push MSG    ; print welcome message
    call printf
    add esp,4   ; clean the stack 

    call printArray ;print the unsorted array

    ;parameters
    ;push len
    ;push array
    mov eax, len
    mov ebx, array
    push eax
    push ebx

    call myInsertionSort
    call printArray

    mov eax, 1  ;exit system call
    int 0x80

printArray:
    push ebp    ;save old frame pointer
    mov ebp,esp ;create new frame on stack
    pusha       ;save registers

    mov eax,0
    mov ebx,0
    mov edi,0

    mov esi,0   ;array index
    mov bl, byte [len]
    add edi,ebx ; edi = array size

print_loop:
    cmp esi,edi
    je print_end
    push dword [array+4*esi]
    push S1
    call printf
    add esp, 8  ;clean the stack
    inc esi
    jmp  print_loop
print_end:
    popa        ;restore registers
    mov esp,ebp ;clean the stack frame
    pop ebp     ;return to old stack frame
    ret

myInsertionSort:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    push ebx
    push esi
    push edi
    mov ecx, [ebp+12]
    movzx ecx, byte [ecx]   ;put len in ecx, our loop variable
    mov eax, 4 ; size of one spot in array, one byte
    mov ebx, 0
    mov esi, [ebp+8] ; the array
    loop loop_1
    loop_1:
        cmp eax, ecx ; if we're done
        jge done_1 ; then done with loop
        push ecx ; we save len, because loop command decrements ecx
        mov ecx, [esi+eax] ; ecx now array[i]
        mov ebx, eax
        shr ebx, 2 ; number of times for inner loop
        loop_2:
            cmp ebx, 0 ; we don't use loop to not affect ecx so we use ebx and compare it manually with 0
            jl done_2
            cmp [esi+ebx], ecx ;we see if array[ebx] os ecx so we can exit the loop
            jle done_2
            lea edx, [esi+ebx]
            push dword [edx] ; pushing our array[ebx]
            add edx, eax
            pop dword [edx] ; poping the last one
            dec ebx ; decrementing the loop iterator
            jmp loop_2 ; looping again
        done_2:
            mov [esi+ebx+1], ecx
            inc eax ; incrementing iterator
            pop ecx ; len of array to compare now to eax and see if we're done
            jmp loop_1
    done_1:
        pop edi
        pop esi
        pop ebx
        pop ebp ; we pop them in opposite to how we pushed
        ret
```

The output of the program is:

```
welcome to sortMe, please sort me
5
1
7
3
4
9
12
8
10
2
6
11
```

Up to now it's the unsorted array, and then the program outputs:

```
327681
1280
0
5
4
9
12
8
10
2
6
11
```

Any clue why is it happening? Where is the problem? I went through with `gdb` but it's not clear why the array is the following. Is the problem with the sorting or the printing?

Comment: You need to increment your pointer by 4 in `print_loop` since that's the size of a dword. Actually in your code it's better to use `push dword [array+4*esi]` for the same reason.

Comment: @Jester Thank you! But now the output is weird, it isn't sorted (?)

Comment: Your comment says `print the unsorted array` and indeed that's what you are doing ... so why do you expect it to be sorted? :)

Comment: @Jester I actually did print the array again, I modified the code again here so it'd fit. The output is updated too.

Comment: You at least have the same issues in the sorting as in the printing, you are not scaling by 4. Apart from that, use gdb to step through your code and see where it deviates from your intentions.

Comment: @Jester Do you know any working algorithm online that might be working? I want to compare mine

Answer (score 0):

After you `call myInsertionSort` you still have to cleanup the stack with `add esp,8`!
The *exit system call* uses EBX too.

**Is the problem with the sorting or the printing?** The printing works correctly but you could clean up the code a bit.
There's no need for the classic prolog/epilog and the clearing of EAX is useless.
In *printArray* change `pusha/popa` by `pushad/popad`.

I think the code of *myInsertionSort* is kind of unsalvageable. Here is my version of an insertion sort:

```
myInsertionSort:
 pushad                  ;This uses 32 bytes on the stack
 mov     ebp,esp
 mov     ebx,[ebp+32+4]  ;Address of array
 mov     ecx,[ebp+32+8]  ;Address of len
 movzx   ecx,byte [ecx]  ;len
 sub     ecx,1
 jbe     .exit           ;Nothing to sort
 xor     edi,edi         ;Index of candidate
.start:
 inc     edi 
 mov     eax,[ebx+edi*4] ;Value of candidate
 xor     esi,esi         ;Index within the underlying elements
.find:
 cmp     [ebx+esi*4],eax
 jg      .insert
 add     esi,1
 cmp     esi,edi
 jb      .find
 jmps    .next           ;No insertion needed
.insert:
 xchg    [ebx+esi*4],eax
 add     esi,1
 cmp     esi,edi
 jb      .insert
 mov     [ebx+esi*4],eax
.next:
 cmp     edi,ecx
 jb      .start
.exit:
 popad
 ret
```